# Fubini's Thm Change of Variables

Tags: integration, analysis

[image]

For part a, how does the change of variables affect the domain of integration?
Since x ranges from 1 to infinity does letting y = ux mean y now ranges from u to infinity?

However this integral gives something in terms of u which doesn't help towards the proof since u isn't specified.

For the second part of a), is that just reversing the order of integration?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $0 \leqslant y < \infty$ and $1 \leqslant x < \infty$.  Hence, $0 < 1/x \leqslant  1$ and $0 \leqslant u =y/x < \infty$. With this change of variables, the lower limit for integration with respect to $u$ will be $0$ , and

\begin{align}&\int_1^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty (x^2 + y^2)^{-\alpha} \, dy \right)\,dx \\&= \int_1^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty x^{-2 \alpha}(1 + u^2)^{-\alpha} x\, du \right)\,dx \\&= \int_1^\infty x^{-2 \alpha+1}\,dx \int_0^\infty (1 + u^2)^{-\alpha}\, du.\end{align}

Therefore, $f$ is integrable on $[1,\infty) \times [0, \infty)$ since the single integrals above are convergent for $\alpha > 1$.

We can switch the order of integration since $f$ is nonnegative and integrable:

$$\int_1^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty (x^2 + y^2)^{-\alpha} \, dy \right)\,dx \\ = \int_0^\infty \left(\int_1^\infty (x^2 + y^2)^{-\alpha} \, dx \right)\,dy. $$

Since the integrand is symmetric with respect to $x$ and $y$ we see that $f$ is integrable on $[0,\infty) \times [1,\infty)$ and $[0,1] \times [1,\infty) = \left( [0,\infty) \times [1,\infty) \right) \setminus \left( (1,\infty) \times [1,\infty) \right).$

Note that $g$ is continuous and, hence, integrable on $[-1,1]^2$. Since $g(x,y) = (1 + x^2 + y^2)^{-\alpha} \leqslant (x^2 + y^2)^{-\alpha} = f(x,y)$ then the integrability of $f$ implies that $g$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus [-1,1]^2$. Thus $g$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense. Thank you! Although how would I go about deducing that g is integrable on the whole of R^2?